# How do spells work in D&D Essentials Starter kit?

Tags: dnd-4e

I have this starter kit. I first made a fighter (easy in my mind), but now I am making a Wizard. I don't understand how the Hypnotism spell works. I don't throw anything?

> Attack:*_* (Intelligence) VS Will

My wizard has Intelligence 18.
 For example, I use the spell hypnotism on a gnome and then gnome tries to use WILL to Defend?
And I don't roll any dice? Does this also mean when using magic missiles only the creature is rolling the dice?

Comment: How much of the rules have you read?

Comment: cover to cover but some things just dont make sense. Ok so in the Hypnotism card in the Attack i but my Intell modifier ? so d20+4 vs (Monster) Will d20+something ?   This card make this so hard to understand http://puu.sh/6AgJv.png there is (Intelligence and Intelligence modifier word... thats why thought you but in the first line 18 and second +4 ?

Comment: Ok, hopefully my answer, and the Q&A I linked above will help you understand attack powers. Let me know in the comments below my answer if I can clarify anything for you. The monster doesn't roll. Defenses start at 10+half level+stat mod.

Comment: They both mean modifier. The target and Hit lines you different terms to indicate different uses. Target lines get 1/2 level applied, damage doesn't.

Comment: Any pre-made monsters should have defenses listed alreay as part of their "stat block"

Comment: OK thanx for clarity that B) and sorry for my bad english. Ok now i can go adventure with my fighter/wizard lovers

Answer (score 5):

You've got two different questions here. This goes down into a pretty fundamental level of how basic attack powers work in 4e.

Attack powers have 4 basic lines.

- Target
- Hit
- Effect
- Miss

The target line tells you what defense the power targets. This is where you roll your d20. then you add any relevant modifiers (stat mod ((stat - 10)/2), half level, any other "to hit" bonuses). If your roll exceeds the target's stated defense then you have hit.

The hit line is where you add your damage (stat mod, any other relevant damage bonuses). Only use this if you hit.

The effect line *always* happens. No matter the result of the power, the text on the effect line should be followed.

The miss line happens if you miss. Only powers that do something on a miss have a miss line.

So for the power Hypnotism, it has a Target line (Int vs Will), this means you roll a d20 and add your Intelligence modifier (in this case 4). Then you compare that to the target's will defense.

For Magic Missile, that power *only* has and Effect line, so you just apply the damage, there is no attack or damage roll.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that for magic missile you don't even roll damage, it's just 2+Int modifier?

Comment: @AdrianoVaroliPiazza good catch, you're right, it's static now

Comment: The more I deal with Essentials as 'part of' 4E, the more I want to beat in my own brains. They may use all the same things, but they are completely different games.